# Clarification of TensorFlow AttentionWrapper's Layer Size

Tags: tensorflow

In `tensorflow.contrib.seq2seq`'s `AttentionWrapper`, what does "depth" refer to as stated in the `attention_layer_size` documentation? When the documentation says to "use the context as attention" if the value is `None`, what is meant by "the context"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Neural Machine Translation by Jointly Learning to Align and Translate](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0473) they give a description of the (Bahdanau) attention mechanism; essentially what happens is that you compute scalar "alignment scores" `a_1, a_2, ..., a_n` that indicate how important each element of your encoded input sequence is at a given moment in time (i.e. which part of the input sentence you should pay attention to right now in the current timestep).

Assuming your (encoded) input sequence that you want to "pay attention"/"attend over" is a sequence of vectors denoted as `e_1, e_2, ..., e_n`, the context vector at a given timestep is the weighted sum over all of these as determined by your alignment scores:

`context = c := (a_1*e_1) + (a_2*e_2) + ... + (a_n*e_n)`

(Remember that the `a_k`'s are scalars; you can think of this as an "averaged-out" letter/word in your sentence --- so ideally if your model is trained well, the context looks most similar to the `e_i` you want to pay attention to the most, but bears a little bit of resemblance to `e_{i-1}`, `e_{i+1}`, etc. Intuitively, think of a "smeared-out" input element, if that makes any sense...)

Anyway, if `attention_layer_size` is not `None`, then it specifies the number of hidden units in a feedforward layer within your decoder that is used to mix this context vector with the output of the decoder's internal RNN cell to get the attention value. If `attention_layer_size == None`, it just uses the context vector above as the attention value, and no mixing of the internal RNN cell's output is done. (When I say "mixing", I mean that the context vector and the RNN cell's output are concatenated and then projected to the dimensionality that you specify by setting `attention_layer_size`.)

The relevant part of the implementation is at [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/attention_wrapper.py#L731) and has a description of how it's computed.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That was super helpful! If I can ask two follow up questions, (1) is there a recommended attention_layer_size? (2) can you provide some intuition for when to use concatenation and projection, and when to just use the context vector?

Comment: I've set the `attention_layer_size` to somewhere in the order of hundreds of hidden units before with good results, but it's dependent on the task at hand (I generally try to overfit first with a large number of hidden units and then minimize it until it is as low as it can get while keeping validation-set performance good). FWIW, in the neural machine translation paper it's around the hundreds I think (the mixing is really more of a matrix projection than a feedforward NN, as there isn't an activation; I slightly misspoke above).

I would generally use both context & RNN output.

Comment: Alright, thank you! I'm struggling to debug my sequence to sequence model. Since it sounds like you have experience in this area, can I email you?

Comment: IMO it makes more sense to edit your original question with further context/info unless you have a specific reason why you would prefer email, as keeping any details/potential resolution of the question on this page would benefit future readers that might be looking for help with this same issue.

Comment: I agree with you, but my questions aren't related to this original post. I posted my new questions on StackOverflow as well. If you have time to help me with either, I'd appreciate it!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706150/tensorflow-seq2seq-training-time-per-minibatch-monotonically-increases

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704253/how-to-correctly-use-tensorflow-tensorflow-contrib-seq2seq