# How to correctly use TensorFlow tensorflow.contrib.seq2seq

Tags: tensorflow

I'm misusing TensorFlow's `tf.contrib.seq2seq` module in some manner, but no errors are produced so I'm having trouble find the bug. My problem is that my decoder outputs the same value (in my case, a categorical label between 0 and 3, inclusive) for every output in the output sequence. In the below example, my output sequence has 8 labels.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVl4O.png)

My code:

```
attention_mechanism = BahdanauAttention(num_units=ATTENTION_UNITS,
                                        memory=encoder_outputs,
                                        normalize=True)

attention_wrapper = AttentionWrapper(cell=self._create_lstm_cell(DECODER_SIZE),
                                     attention_mechanism=attention_mechanism,
                                     attention_layer_size=None)

attention_zero = attention_wrapper.zero_state(batch_size=self.x.shape[0], dtype=tf.float32)

# concatenate c1 and c2 from encoder final states
new_c = tf.concat([encoder_final_states[0].c, encoder_final_states[1].c], axis=1)

# concatenate h1 and h2 from encoder final states
new_h = tf.concat([encoder_final_states[0].h, encoder_final_states[1].h], axis=1)

# define initial state using concatenated h states and c states
init_state = attention_zero.clone(cell_state=LSTMStateTuple(c=new_c, h=new_h))

training_helper = TrainingHelper(inputs=self.y_actual,  # feed in ground truth
                                 sequence_length=output_length)  # feed in sequence length

decoder = BasicDecoder(cell=attention_wrapper,
                       helper=training_helper,
                       initial_state=init_state
                       )

decoder_outputs, decoder_final_state, decoder_final_sequence_lengths = dynamic_decode(decoder=decoder,
                                                                                      impute_finished=True)
```

I need to create the `LSTMStateTuple` because my encoder uses a bidirectional RNN.

I suspect that the error is in the decoder because the outputs of my encoder don't have any appearance of uniformity. However, I could be wrong.

Comment: Is there any difference if you set `attention_layer_size` to some arbitrary positive integer?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to make a difference. However, I tried setting `output_attention=False` in my `AttentionWrapper`, and this seems to work (which makes sense, because the default `output_attention=True` is intended to work with Luong attention, not Bahdanau attention. I'll post an answer when I can confirm my suspicions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed that I needed to set `output_attention=False` because I am using Bahdanau Attention.