# TensorFlow Seq2Seq Training Time per Minibatch Monotonically Increases

Tags: tensorflow

I'm training a `tensorflow.contrib.seq2seq` encoder-decoder model, and the training time per minibatch is monotonically increasing.

`Step Number: 10 Elapsed time: 52.89215302467346 Loss: 1.0420862436294556    Metrics: {'accuracy': 0.22499999}
Step Number: 20 Elapsed time: 60.28505992889404 Loss: 0.8007364869117737    Metrics: {'accuracy': 0.28}
Step Number: 30 Elapsed time: 73.98479580879211 Loss: 0.7292348742485046    Metrics: {'accuracy': 0.34}
Step Number: 40 Elapsed time: 82.99069213867188 Loss: 0.6843382120132446    Metrics: {'accuracy': 0.345}
Step Number: 50 Elapsed time: 86.97363901138306 Loss: 0.6808319687843323    Metrics: {'accuracy': 0.38999999}
Step Number: 60 Elapsed time: 106.96697807312012    Loss: 0.601255476474762 Metrics: {'accuracy': 0.44}
Step Number: 70 Elapsed time: 124.17725801467896    Loss: 0.5971778035163879    Metrics: {'accuracy': 0.405}
Step Number: 80 Elapsed time: 137.91252613067627    Loss: 0.596596896648407 Metrics: {'accuracy': 0.43000001}
Step Number: 90 Elapsed time: 146.6834409236908 Loss: 0.5921837687492371    Metrics: {'accuracy': 0.42500001}`

All my data are artificially generated and are sampled randomly, meaning that (in general) there should be no difference between minibatches early in training and minibatches later in training. Additionally, all my data have the same input sequence length and the same output sequence length. Why might my model take longer to train later minibatches?

I found this relevant [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230559/processing-time-gets-longer-and-longer-after-each-iteration-tensorflow), but I'm not changing my computational graph during my training loop.

To show some code, let's start in `main`:

```
def main(_):
    x_minibatch, y_minibatch, y_lengths_minibatch = construct_data_pipeline()

    model = import_model()

    train(model=model, x_minibatch=x_minibatch, y_minibatch=y_minibatch, y_lengths_minibatch=y_lengths_minibatch)
```

```

My data is stored as `SequenceExample`s, one per `TFRecord` file. My `construct_data_pipeline()` function is defined as follows:

```
def construct_data_pipeline():
    # extract TFRecord filenames located in data directory
    tfrecord_filenames = []
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(tf.app.flags.FLAGS.data_dir):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith('.tfrecord'):
                tfrecord_filenames.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

    # read and parse data from TFRecords into tensors
    x, y, x_len, y_len = construct_examples_queue(tfrecord_filenames)

    # group tensors into minibatches
    x_minibatch, y_minibatch, y_lengths_minibatch = construct_minibatches(x=x, y=y,
                                                                      y_len=y_len,
                                                                      x_len=x_len)

    return x_minibatch, y_minibatch, y_lengths_minibatch
```

Stepping into `construct_examples_queue()`

```
def construct_examples_queue(tfrecords_filenames):
    number_of_readers = tf.flags.FLAGS.number_of_readers

    with tf.name_scope('examples_queue'):
        key, example_serialized = tf.contrib.slim.parallel_reader.parallel_read(tfrecords_filenames,
                                                                            tf.TFRecordReader,
                                                                            num_readers=number_of_readers)

        x, y, x_len, y_len = parse_example(example_serialized)

        return x, y, x_len, y_len
```

I don't think I can show `parse_example`, since the data isn't my own. The main parts are that I specify what I expect the `SequenceExample` to contain and then call

```
    context_parsed, sequence_parsed = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(example_serialized,
                                                                   context_features=context_features,
                                                                   sequence_features=sequence_features)
```

Skipping ahead to how I construct minibatches, I use

```
def construct_minibatches(x, y, y_len, x_len,
                      bucket_boundaries=list(range(400, tf.app.flags.FLAGS.max_x_len, 100))):

    batch_size = tf.app.flags.FLAGS.batch_size

    with tf.name_scope('batch_examples_using_buckets'):
        _, outputs = tf.contrib.training.bucket_by_sequence_length(input_length=len_x,
                                                               tensors=[x, y, y_len],
                                                               batch_size=batch_size,
                                                               bucket_boundaries=bucket_boundaries,
                                                               dynamic_pad=True,
                                                               capacity=2 * batch_size,
                                                               allow_smaller_final_batch=True)

        x_minibatch = outputs[0]
        y_minibatch = outputs[1]
        y_lengths_minibatch = outputs[2]
        return x_minibatch, y_minibatch, y_lengths_minibatch
```

Note: I had to change some variable names for privacy issues. Hopefully I didn't make any mistakes.

Comment: silly question, but you're sure it's not elapsed time since the start of training? What generates "elapsed time"?

Comment: The loss is steadily decreasing, too.

Comment: Elapsed time is initialized as `start_time = time.time()`. Then, after training on 10 minibatches, I call `print(time.time() - start_time)` and then `start_time = time.time()`.

Comment: To be more precise, I actually call `print('Step Number: {}\tElapsed time: {}\tLoss: {}\tMetrics: {}'.format(step_number + 1, time.time() - start_time, loss, metrics))`

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without having more details, including the parts of the code where you feed in data and call session.run.

Comment: Give me two minutes to add code.

Comment: Or 14 minutes :D Still learning how to format code here.

Comment: I got an answer from faddey-w on GitHub that pointed out the mistake I was making. I was changing my computational graph - I just didn't know it. Link to his answer: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8057

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to [faddy-w](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8057#issuecomment-310505897) for solving two of my problems simultaneously!

It turns out I was changing my computational graph without knowing it.

I was calling

```
sess.run([model.optimizer.minimize(model.loss), model.y_predicted_logits],
                                 feed_dict={model.x: x_values,
                                            model.y_actual: y_values,
                                            model.y_actual_lengths: y_lengths_values})
```

from within a loop, where

```
model.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=self.y_actual,
                                                                      logits=self.y_predicted_logits))
```

and

```
model.optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=initial_learning_rate)
```

without knowing that `optimizer.minimize()` adds additional operations to my graph.